# improving regex that matches {m,n}|{m,}|{,n}|{n} in the beginning of the line

Tags: java, regex

Need a regex that will match either of {m,n}|{m,}|{,n}|{n} (where m and n are integer numbers) with arbitrary number of spaces in between symbols in the beginning of the line. I came up with this:

^({\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*}|{\s*,\s*\d+\s*}|{\s*\d+\s*,\s*}|{\s*\d+\s*})

While it certainly works, I was curious if there is a way to make it shorter. Thanks for input.

UPDATE: Mark proposed an excellent solution:
^\{(\s*\d+\s*(,(\s*\d+\s*)?)?|,\s*\d+\s*)\}

Comment: Are you using regex to match a regex?

Comment: Yes :) I know, a bit weird, but I am writing a little parser for a simplified regex notation for a project I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this, at the very least (ignoring spaces for now for brevity):

```
"^\\{(\\d+(,(\\d+)?)?|,\\d+)\\}"
```

This captures all but the {,n} case in the first alternative.

Adding spaces back in:

```
"^\\{\\s*(\\d+(\\s*,(\\s*\\d+)?)?|,\\s*\\d+)\\s*\\}"
```

May not look shorter but remember I'm properly escaping things for Java where you are certainly not.

Comment: you are missing a closing bracket - ^{(\d+(,(\d)?)?)|,\d+}
. Thanks, this is the level of brevity I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

For one, they all start with `{\s*` and end with `\s*}`. So you can at least "refactor those out:

`^{\s*(\d+\s*,\s*\d+|,\s*\d+|\d+\s*,|\d+)\s*}`